# how to put variables inside curly braces in jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am developing an application with laravel and jquery. In Jquery ajax part, i have dynamic url for each pages.
Code

```
 $(document).on('click','.assignFlagClass',function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var routeName = $(this).data('route');
        var url = `route('${routeName}')`;
        
        $('#assignFlagModal').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ "+url+" }}",
            data: {id:id},
            method: 'get',
            success: function(res)
            {
                alert(res);
            }
        });
    });
```

Expected Url output
***localhost:8000/slug/id***
Output
***localhost:8000+url+?id=1***

Comment: Why do you want curly braces ? No need curly beaced just assign such as url:url

Comment: @sameerAhmed have tried that as well but output is relatively same

Comment: You can't pass a javascript variable to a php function. php runs on server and doesn't exist in browser. Also using `data` object in a GET will always create the url query string with `?somprop=someval`. If you want a different url structure you need to build the url string yourself and get rid of `data`

Comment: if i Put url: "{{ route('routeName') }} " then it works completely fine... i just want that routeName to be dynamic

Comment: So just provide the base path and build the rest of the string using the element data

Comment: @charlietfl that is the solution but the problem arises when i change prefix later on. for eg: now i have localhost:8000/system/slug/id ....but that "SYSTEM" might change due to client requirements and i have to change each an every jquery ajax "system" to another

Comment: So why can't that be sent to js variable? Or perhaps you need to send it in query striing `?action=system&id=1`

Comment: "_but that "SYSTEM" might change due to client requirements_" That's why you use "named" routes. `{{ route('system') }}` ... "system" here is the _name_ of the route, that shouldn't change too often. Instead, the _name_ of the route stays the same, but the _URL_ for that route can be changed as often as you want _without_ having to update every jquery ajax

Comment: "_i just want that routeName to be dynamic_" Not sure you really want that. You'd have to create a lot of "_named_" routes in your web.php beforehand. Might want to read up on how [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function() {
        var url = "{{ route("query") }}";
    })
</script>
```

This will only work if you dont have any values/paramters in your url .. if your url is dynamic then you cannot use that route from your jquery because when the DOM is ready you wont have the variables required for the route . One thing you can do is load that jquery only after the page is completely loaded .

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            var url = '{{ route("query") }}'
        })

    </script>
```